# Active record is not display table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

As working on the Active Record as i have work on different function for active reocrd like Avg, sum and count as it display working fine and also Chart,

but one things is baffle me and i still cannot get it working and it should be working fine, as i cannot get display all data list table like

```
 <table id="dttb" class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th> full name </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
            <tbody>
              <% @user.each do |user| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= user.fullname %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

as it should be working as the error is kept displayed

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

as I look up information and most of them are mention .each do, seems I am doing wrong as I have used

```
<%= User.count(:user) %>
```

and

```
<%= column_chart User.group(:provider).count(:user) %>
```

and it seems working fine as query function.

so I tried again with find_each

```
 <% User.find_each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= puts user.fullname %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

and the error is gone but it does not display at the data and it's show blanks unless I put 'link_to' but they keep display like

[image]

and I have put on AdminController.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  @user = User.all 
  @tools = Tool.all 
  end
end
```

seems I miss something, I have look google or stackover flow, most of them answer are very same as this code as I wrote

Update: as I am able to get some data like a phone number or email

[image]

Here is code i wrote

```
 <% User.find_each do |user| %>
 <tr>
     <td><%= link_to user.id, user  %></td>
     <td><%= link_to user.email, user %></td>
     <td><%= link_to user.created_at.strftime('%v'), user %></td>
     <td><%= link_to user.fullname, user  %></td>
     <td><%= link_to user.phone_number, user %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
```

but frustration with fullname as it should be displayed but it not

[image]

Comment: Please, change `<% User.find_each do |user| %>` to `<% @user.each do |user| %>` in the last snippet. Is it still working?

Comment: yes,  sadly it not working as it displays "  undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" if I change 'each' to 'find_each' and it working

Comment: You are no setting `@user` in your controller, that's why it says no method for nil. What's the name of the view's file?

Comment: the name of view files is _data.html.erb under admin pages as use this data under render   <%= render 'admin/data' %> on the http://localhost:3000/admin , the @user is working in all pages apart from this data

Comment: Please, rename `@user` in index action to something else, like `@my_users`, and use that variable on your snippet.

Comment: ok i have changed as your request and the error is still same with each if i change to find_each and it working but same as previous with @each as the second screenshot

Comment: Then `index` is not the action you are calling. Find out what action are you actually calling and add `@users = User.all` to it.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at it and if I found out and will get back to you, as I tried to another data list based on Tools and it displays fine, and another too apart from user.

Comment: as found this issue, it was another code block it and i fix it and it display correct,

Comment: Glad to know it! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `@user` (or better `@users`) in the controller:

```rb
def index # or the actual action name
  @users = User.all # or User.order(:fullname)
end
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for not get back quicker, yes i have it already as forgot mention on it, and it still not display at all only user/17 if i put link_to

Comment: It seems `@user` contains a single User, then. Not a collection, which is necessary for `each`. Please, update your question posting the controller's action.